# NullPointerException with Android API18 and fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I've created a new project with Android Studio v3.2, used API 18 and it created the default app just fine.

I added a spinner to the `fragment` file (First time I am using it, I am not sure if this is the problem).

No I simply wanted to add some dummy items to the spinner on the fly but my app keeps crashing with Unofrotunately....has stopped message.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_start);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    //Just added this!
    String[] movies = new String[]{"one, two, three"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> movieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.app_start_select_movie_spinner, movies );
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.app_start_select_movie_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
}
```

Here is the message in logcat:

```
11-06 23:57:29.174  16743-16743/org.pervasivesystems.nexusmosaic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.pervasivesystems.nexusmosaic/org.pervasivesystems.nexusmosaic.activity_app_start}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.pervasivesystems.nexusmosaic.activity_app_start.onCreate(activity_app_start.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line 32 is:

```
spinner.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
```

So basically the `spinner` is null...somehow it couldnt be assigned

It might be very simple but I couldnt figure it out :(

Comment: What's activity_app_start.java line 32?

Comment: spinner.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

Comment: its already there in the question, in the `onCreate` method

Comment: no that doesn't compile

Comment: Try using a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]`

Comment: The problem is the spinner is assigned to null, somehow it can not be find in R.id  maybe because it is in the fragment layout which was created by default by android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same resource for both the spinner and the adapter spinner item (which expects a pointer to a layout resource file, not a view object).

```
ArrayAdapter<String> movieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.app_start_select_movie_spinner, movies );
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.app_start_select_movie_spinner);
```

Instead, try:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> movieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, movies );
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.app_start_select_movie_spinner);
```

Also, try moving adapter initialisation into your fragment's onCreateView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

        String[] movies = new String[]{"one, two, three"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> movieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, movies );
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.app_start_select_movie_spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        return rootView;
}
```

For accessing the fragment from the activity, have a look at the [fragment google dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

In essence, you can get the fragment's root view from your activity by using the following code, but it can be a bit hit and miss:

```
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findViewById(R.id.your_fragment);
if(yourFragment != null)
{
    View fragmentRootView = (View) yourFragment.getView();
    //do your manipulation here.
}
```

Comment: I noticed that problem, I fixed that but still the main problem is that `spinner` is still null and causes crash! somehow I should find its id from the fragment not the activiy layout.

Comment: Yeah, I've attempted to solve your problem in the second part of my answer.

Comment: Hey thanks taht solved the problem. Can you tell me how can I still setup the spinner in the oncreate of the main activity? I mean how to get a reference to rootView in main activity?

Comment: Yeah, you can get the fragment from the (YourFragment) fragmentmanager.findViewById()